# scala - make variable available inside block

Tags: scala

Having a function that is used like this:

```
xpto.withClient {
  client => client.abcd
}
```

I would like to wrap it in an object:

```
object X {
  def foo[T](block: => T): T = {
    xpto.withClient {
      client => {
        block
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to make it possible to be used like this:

```
object Y {
  def bar : Unit {
    X.foo {
      client.abcd
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't seems to be making the client value available inside the block though. Is this possible? Making the client variable available inside the block definition? I've looked around with implicits in Scala but so far no good.

Comment: Do allow this sanely, you would need something like Haskell's implicit parameters. Note that these end up in the type of the functions in Haskell, or type safety would greatly suffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work, because `block` is just something that produces a value of `T`. It doesn't have the same scope. Supposing that `client` has type `Client`, then `block` should be a function `Client => T`. `foo` would then pass the `client` to `block`.

```
def foo[T](block: Client => T): T = {
    xpto.withClient { client =>
        block(client)
    }
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
def foo[T](block: Client => T): T = xpto.withClient(block(_))
```

However, that will change your usage to this:

```
object Y {
  def bar : Unit {
    X.foo { client =>
      client.abcd
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this does nothing but thinly wrap `xpto.withClient`. The thing is, you need to have a way to pass `client` down the chain. Doing this implicitly won't really help either, because you still need a `client` identifier within that anonymous block of code.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was trying to avoid having to name the client in the X.foo but I guess it won't be possible. I understood your solution and how it would work though.